# How to generate partial views from string in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

In my project i have a Model that has a string property which contains content with razor standards. I need to compile the property to showing html result.

In viewModel i have code like following:

```
public class PluginContent{
public string Content {private set;get;}
private void FillContent() {
 Content ="@{int count=10; fore (int i=0;i<count;i++) <b>@i.toString() </b>}";
}
public PluginContent(){
FillContent()
}
}
```

And in razor view i have:

```
@model plugincontent

<h3>Your content is: </h3>
@Html.Raw(Model.Content)
```

I thought Html.Raw cans help me, but it does not. I need to render this string content like a standard partial views.

Comment: What real problem are you trying to solve? Why do you generate Razor code in your controller/model? Why don't you create a partial view in the first place? If you want to compose different partial views you can use `@Html.Partial` with a view's name. If you want to compose different MVC components you can use `@Html.Display`. MVC supports composition out-of-the-box.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , My main scenario is big, i want to get and show html codes from a method or property that is in a plugin (not in the main project). this plugin gets views from assembly embedded resources and returns it as string. I don't want to create controller in plugin for tiny results.
I can send imodule(which is interface for my plugins) with viewbag or model to view, and if i can compile the strings to html at runtime my scenario is fully done.

Comment: MVC already has a similar concept, the Html helpers. The way you try to do it now violates the MVC architecture. Razor code is all about the *views*. It shouldn't be generated by the ViewModel.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, but i want generate it by View. I send a standard razor code to view with a model, and in view i want generate standard html code from this. And thin this is quite in accordance with the mvc architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do what you are looking for exactly. What I would do in a similar situation is write a method that returns the required HTML (instead of Razor to generate the HTML) and call that from the view.

Something like:

```
public IHtmlString Content()
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
sb.Append("<b>");
sb.Append(i.ToString());
sb.Append("</b>");    
}

     return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

If you really want to have Razor to generate the HTML look at something like

- https://github.com/volkovku/RazorTemplates or
- http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

Comment: The OP asks how to display the content string, not how to generate it. Anyway, ASP.NET MVC already supports partial views. In Razor you just need to type `@Html.Partial(...)`

Comment: This is not my answer, i need a way to compile my string in runtime, like "eval" method in javascript.

Comment: The libraries I pointed out allow you to compile your strings at runtime. For instance (from RazorTemplates README): `var template = Template.Compile("Hello @Model.Name!");
Console.WriteLine(template.Render(new { Name = "World" }));`

Comment: @FriedHoeben, thanks a lot,  your links can help me in some scenarios. they are very good.

Comment: @Taymaz, Do the links help enough to mark my answer as correct?

Comment: @FriedHoeben, Your links is correct but i think they are not ideal, because mvc internally has capability to compile razor codes, i want to find a way to use this capability. "RazorTemplates" and "razorEngine" are good for non asp.net mvc projects.